Is honey good or bad for kids?
The Rambam (Deot 4:12) says הַדְּבַשׁ וְהַיַּיִן רַע לַקְּטַנִּים, honey and wine are bad for kids.
The Rashi on Yevamot 75b says לחם יפה לבחורים ושמן לזקנים ודבש לתינוקות, bread is good for the young men, oil for the elders and honey for the children.
Is honey good for kids or not?

I think Rashi is talking about taste, not nutritional value, but then in other places the taste of the man is conflated with its nutritional value (see Rashi Bamidbar 11:5) so I'm not sure

Kudos to Rashi for not just pushing wine.

Honey contains small amount of pollen, which is an allergen. By taking honey, a person accustoms oneself to small amounts of pollen, which prevents him or her from strong allergies in spring. Also one needs sugar for mental work.

The British National Health Service says
"Occasionally, honey contains bacteria that can produce toxins in a baby's intestines, leading to infant botulism, which is a very serious illness.
Do not give your child honey until they're over 1 year old. Honey is a sugar, so avoiding it will also help prevent tooth decay."

Is it “honey” or “mead”?

Although Rashi says that honey is good for kids the simple reading of the Gemara is that the Manna tasted like honey for the kids.
It is interesting to note that the Eitz Yosef on Shemos Rabba, has a slightly different Nusach than the Gemara.

אלא שהמן טעמו הטבעי טעם לחם היו לבחורים. וטעם דבש לזקנים. וטעם שמן
לתינוקות

Tosefta Sota Chapter 4:1 also seems to say that for the kids it was like oil.

לשד השמן כיוצא מן הדד [שמן] מה דד זה עיקר לתינוק והכל טפל כך היה המן
עיקר לישראל והכל טפל [להם] ד"א מה הדד [זה] אפי' תינוק יונק [הימנו] כל
היום [אין מזיקו כך נעשה] המן שאפילו ישראל אוכלו כל היום כולו [אין
מזיקו כך] נעשה למי שאין נחשב עליו אבל מי שנחשב עליו מתהפך בפיו לכל
איזה טעם שירצה


Unlike real honey, Manna doesn't carry a risk of botulism

@Heshy Can confirm, I have never heard of a documented case of botulism secondary to manna ingestion.

How about stone honey?

Rashi says the Manna tasted like honey for the kids. The gemara says that. Rashi explains it's because לחם יפה לבחורים etc. Usually that means beneficial.

The point for the kids is relevant because the children's taste sensors are not developed and they have a taste of food very different from the adults'

Doctors strongly recommend that children under the age of 1 not consume honey due to the risk of infant botulism which is very dangerous and life threatening. See here...
I'm not sure Rashi is saying precisely that it's healthy for children but that children like honey more than adults. Either way the time in which honey is dangerous for children is limited to when they are infants.
Wine and all alcohol will affect children significantly more than an adult and should be avoided as well. See here for the serious risks of giving a child alcohol...

+1 At the time of Gemara, women nursed their children for 2 years after birth. That's why such issues were not common.
